# Use through model fields in queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given this for a through model from List (I've tried to use some generic models/fields as my actual models are industry specific),

```
class List( models.Model ):
    members = models.ManyToManyField( User, through='ListMembership')
    ...

class ListMembership( models.Model ):
    member = models.ForeinKey( User )
    list = models.ForeignKey( List )
    member_accepted = models.BooleanField( default=False )
    list_accepted = models.BooleanField( default=False )
    ...
```

I am attempting to use the through model in a queryset of List. I want to get all Lists where the current logged in user is a member and is accepted by both the user (`member_accepted`) and the list (`list_accepted`).

This would work if I just cared about the members and didn't care about the extra through model fields.

```
qs = List.objects.filter(members = self.request.user)
```

I want to get at the through fields.

```
#this is wrong, but this gives an idea of what I am attempting to do
qs = List.objects.filter(members__through__member_accepted=True, members__through__list_accepted=True)
```

**edit to give an example of what I am trying not to do**

```
#this works, but I want to avoid the extra query
through_lists = ListMembership.objects.filter(member = request.user, member_accepted=True, list_accepted=True).values_list('list__pk', flat=True)
qs = List.objects.filter(pk__in=through_lists)
```

Comment: Hi. Do you use double query to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

This one should actually work:

```
qs = List.objects.filter(
        members__member=request.user,
        members__member_accepted=True,
        members__list_accepted=True
     )
```

Please pay attention to the double underscore.

Comment: Isn't members already the Users (not pointing to the through table)? ie...in this example you're asking for the user on a user, the member_accepted on a user, and the list_accepted on a user. What is really wanted is the member_accepted on the through and the list_accepted on the through. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This query should return all lists (List objects) where the conditions are satisfied. The statement ``members__member=request.user`` can be shortened to ``members=request.user``. The result should be queryset of all Lists where ``members`` is the logged in user and ``member_accepted`` and ``list_accepted`` of the associated ListMembership are true. Did you try the query? Play around with it. As I understand your question, this piece of code should get your result straight ahead.

Answer (score 0):

```
through_lists = ListMembership.objects.filter(member = request.user, member_accepted=True, list_accepted=True)
```

Then in `through_lists` you have `ListMembership` instances, just get its list for each instance, without extra query.

```
lists = map(lambda x: x.list,through_lists)
```

Comment: This wouldn't give me a queryset of Lists correct? I guess I didn't specify that I would need a queryset of Lists. Also, I may have oversimplified my example, as there are other reasons I may want to show include a List. I'm using Q() in the actual example and would be missing my "or" Qs if I come from the ListMembership direction on a specific user.